# How to determine general solution using Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

$y′′ + a^2y = 2u(t-10)$

Here $a > 0$ and is any real number. I am confused by $a^2$ value there. Can anyone show me step by step how to get to up to $Y(s)$? It would really help me understand. Thank you.

Comment: Are there conditions for $y(0),y'(0)$?

Comment: Which are variables and which are constants? I am assuming $t$ is a variable, and $a^2$ is constant, but what about $u$?

Comment: $u$ is the unit step function. (Aka $\theta$ or $H$.)

Comment: @Martin, do you know how to write $L[y']$ and $L[y'']$ using $Y(s) = L[y]$?

Comment: @Simon S Yes, I know how to write using those notations. I am mostly just confused by a^2 value there. I don't know how to figure out Y(s) and take the inverse Laplace transform in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take Laplace transform:

$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+a^2Y(s)=\frac{2e^{-10s}}{s}.$$

You can verify that $\mathscr L\{y''\}=s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)$, and that $\mathscr L\{2\,\mathcal U(t-10)\}=\dfrac{2e^{-10s}}{s}$ using the definition $\mathscr L\{f(t)\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$.

For the first part:

$$\mathscr L\{y''\}=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y''(t)dt=e^{-st}y'(0)\Big|_0^\infty- s\int_0^\infty e^{-st}y'(t)\,dt=-y'(0)+s\mathscr L\{y'\}.$$
You can take it from here, the Heaviside step function can be done easily as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, would next step be (s^2Y(s) + a^2)Y(s) - s = 2e^-10s/s?

Comment: Next step you factor out $Y(s)$: $Y(s)[s^2+a^2]=\dfrac{2e^{-10s}}{s}+sy(0)+y'(0)$ And then you apply the inverse of laplace transform.

Comment: That's the part that I am having most trouble with.

Comment: @Martin Which specific expression are you having trouble with? Use [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf).

Comment: I meant I am having trouble figuring out Y(s) =...

Comment: I made the problem more complicated than actually it is. I figured it out. Thanks again for all the help.